# Meteor raix:push notification channelId for android 8.0.0

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo

I have been using raix:push package to send push notifications for android and ios. Its been running fine, but not on android 8.0.

Apparently we need to have a channelId associated with each type of notification for android 8 and above. My push object is as follows :

Meteor version : 1.7.0.3

raix_push version : 3.3.0

```
Push.send({
        from: '',
        title: title,
        text: text,
        NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID : '45664',
        android_channel_id  : '12chdt09',
        channel_id : '79',
        CHANNEL_ID : '81',
        channelID : '123',
        notId : nId,
        gcm: {
            title: title,
            NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID : '45664',
            channelID : '123',
            android_channel_id  : '12chdt09',
            channel_id : '79',
            CHANNEL_ID : '81',
            style:  'inbox',
            summaryText: 'There are %n% notifications '
        },
        payload : {
            id : id
        },
        query: {
            userId: {
                $in: userIds
            },
        },
        "time_to_live" : 2419200
    });
```

I have tried inserting channelId in various ways mentioned above but no positive result yet. Any help?

Comment: refere this link : https://medium.com/cr8resume/notification-in-android-8-0-oreo-implementing-notification-channels-d65b0f81ca50

Comment: So the link creates a public class by the name of NotificationHelper. But where should I call and use this class?

Comment: I tried to find a solution here : https://github.com/raix/push/issues/334 but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Any breakthrough? Facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**My meteor version** : 1.8

**phonegap-plugin-push**@2.2.3

**cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp**@1.4.1

1) [Using this comment](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7600#issuecomment-383327945) add this file to path specified.

2) Adding google-services.json form firebase for your app at `<root>/cordova-build-override/google-services.json`

This configuration worked for me. I am using this in our production no crashes untill now.